# Fill input when user left it empty

Tags: jquery

Im working on simple code which will fill the input when the user will leave it empty.

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
   $('#polewyszukiwarki').click(function(){
      $(this).val('');
      $('#polewyszukiwarki').keypress(function(){
           $(this).css('color', 'black');
      });   
   });



    //THIS PART DOESNT WORK 
    $('#polewyszukiwarki').mouseout.click(function(){

    if($('#polewyszukiwarki').val() == ''){
        $(this).css('color', '#d0d0d0');
            $(this).val('Wpisz nazwę filmu');       
    }

    });

});
```

`.mouseout.click` doesnt work so how i can check if user abandon filling input?

Comment: i would simply add the placeholder to this input without jquery ;)

Comment: why would you want to fill it in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F835Q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/):

```
$('#polewyszukiwarki').focusout(function () {
    if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
        $(this).css('color', '#d0d0d0');
        $(this).val('Wpisz nazwę filmu');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuCHs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.blur`

```
$('#polewyszukiwarki').blur(function()
```

You can also check the value with `this.value`, rather than create an identical selector within that function.